# Browser downloads jpgs, doesn't display them

Tags: browser, download, jpeg, mime-types

My browsers (`Chrome`, `IE` both exhibit this behavior), when faced with an `href` link that points to a `.jpg` file, downloads it rather than displays it. I think perhaps something happened with file associations or `MIME` types, but nothing I mess with seems to fix the problem. Something simple like this:

> <a href="http://site.com/images/image.jpg">image.jpg</a>

will download. Not sure what happened, and no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Unless your question about properly returning images from your site it does not look like programming question...

Comment: What program are .jpg/.jpeg files associated with now?